# Schön Trocken - Bedeutung

Tags: vocabulary

Wenn "schön" "nice(ly)" oder umgangsprachlich "really" bedeuten kann, wie kann ich wissen, welche Bedeutung im folgenden Beispiel gemeint ist?

- Möchtest du auch ein Glas Rotwein?
- Ja, gerne. Is deiner gut? Schön trocken?

Schön trocken = "Nicely dry?" 
oder 
"Really dry?"

Comment: Just as _pretty_ in English, _schön_ kann also have the second meaning of _pretty_ in the sense of "considerable".

Comment: Ist die Frage nicht besser bei [ell](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) oder [elu](https://english.stackexchange.com/) aufgehoben? Immerhin geht es hier um die Übertragung einer eher idiomatischen Wendung von "schön" ins Englische die, bei aller Kompetenz und Hilfsbereitschaft hier, wohl besser von Muttersprachlern eingeordnet werden kann.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach this comment would be an adequate answer. Better than the other answers till now.

Comment: @miep OK, I turned it into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just as *pretty* in English, German *schön* can also have the second meaning of *pretty* in the sense of "considerable".

In your example sentence, *schön trocken* could also mean *nicely dry*. Differentiating whether the meaning of *nicely dry* or *pretty dry* is supposed to be expressed, depends a bit on the context which is not given here.

Comment: +1 Nice answer, although "nicely dry" isn't really natural sounding in English. I can only imagine it in the context of a very wordy wine connoisseur listing off attributes of a wine, but a native speaker wouldn't ask their friend, "Is the wine nicely dry?" [Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nicely+dry%2Cnice+and+dry&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnicely%20dry%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnice%20and%20dry%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cnicely%20dry%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cnice%20and%20dry%3B%2Cc1)

Comment: "Pretty dry" enstpricht eher "ziemlich trocken".

Comment: @PiedPiper Ja, eben "considerable" :-) _Schön trocken?_ Kann doch auch im Deutschen die Bedeutung _Ziemlich trocken?_ haben, oder?

Comment: "Schön trocken" und "ziemlich trocken" können manchmal das Gleiche bedeuten.

Comment: @PiedPiper Das ist doch genau so in meiner Antwort enthalten :-)

Comment: "Schön trocken" würde ich nur mit "Nicely dry" übersetzen. "Ganz schön trocken" oder "Ziemlich trocken" hingegen mit "Pretty dry".

Answer (score 2):

Als einfacher Zusatz könnte man das "schön" bei *schön trocken* als Mischung aus Steigerung und Wertung deuten. Wertend in dem Sinne, dass der Zustand des Weins den Wünschen entspricht und zufriedenstellend ist. Man könnte alternativ auch *angenehm trocken* sagen.
Wie in anderen Antworten angemerkt würde, ändert jedoch ein "ganz" vor dem "schön" die Bedeutung bzw. Wertung ins negative. "Ganz schön trocken" würde eher bedeuten, dass der Wein *zu trocken* ist. "Ganz schön weit", etc... impliziert meist, dass es mehr als gewünscht ist. EDIT: Dies hängt jedoch vom Zusammenhang ab, wie in den Kommentaren genannt, wäre "ganz schön lecker" offensichtlich positiv

Comment: off-topic: bei "ganz schön" gehe ich davon aus, dass es  eine negative Bedeutung kann, wenn es bei Adjektiven verwendet wird, die Negativ sein kann, wenn sie in sehr großer Menge vorliegen (z.B. weit, trocken).  "Ganz schön lecker" wäre doch positiv, oder?

Comment: Stimmt, das hab ich nicht bedacht... Ich pass meine Antwort an.

Comment: Bei "ganz schön lecker" würde ich eher Ironie vermuten

Comment: Alternativ könnte ich es mir auch bei positiver Überraschung vorstellen

Answer (score 2):

Der Aspekt des Angenehmen steht hier im Vordergrund. Daher könnte ein *Pleasently dry* den Eindruck übermitteln.

Answer (score 0):

*Schön trocken* tends to *really* in the meaning of *very*.

Comment: If it had the meaning of "very" you would rather expect the speaker to say ***ganz** schön trocken*. And that would only fit as a comment (the person took a sip and found it actually *to* dry) - as a request, If you ask for a *really* dry wine you would use the direct German equivalent of "very": "sehr".

Answer (score -1):

Im Allgemeinen würde ich sagen, dass *schön trocken* in diesem Zusammenhang mit *nice and dry* zu übersetzen ist. Dies behält den Originalton des Satzes bei – etwas umgangsprachlich, locker und mehr oder weniger positiv.

Wie unten in den Kommentaren bemerkt, gibt es auch die eventuell weniger positive Variante *ganz schön trocken*, was sich besser mit *pretty dry* übersetzen lässt.

---

**Weiteres dazu**

Hier lässt sich das Wort *schön* als [Steigerungspartikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steigerungspartikel) einsetzen. Die genaue Auswirkung solcher Partikeln kann nur grob definiert werden und lässt sich oft nicht direkt übersetzen.

Der Beispielsatz

> Der Wein ist schön trocken

betont, dass es dem Sprecher gefällt, wie besonders trocken der Wein ist, und kann mit

> The wine is nice and dry

gut übersetzt werden.

Der Satz

> Ich habe mich ganz schön gelangweilt

drückt dahingegen eher aus, wie sehr der Sprecher sich gelangweilt hatte – ihm gefiel es aber wahrscheinlich nicht. Das lässt sich auf verschiedene Art und Weise übersetzen:

> I was pretty bored
>   I was bored stiff
>   I was bored to death

Comment: Schön trocken ist auf jeden Fall etwas anderes, als schön und trocken.

Comment: @user unknown, könntest du dann vielleicht ein besser Antwort schreiben?

Comment: @userunknown Ich habe ja auch nicht gesagt, dass es das bedeutet. "Nice and dry" oder "Pretty dry" bedeuten gar nicht, dass der Wein "nice" oder "pretty" sind, sondern sind umgangssprachliche Steigerungspartikeln, die im gesprochenen Englischen häufig vorkommen.

Comment: "Ich habe mich ganz schön gelangweilt" ist kein gutes Beispiel. "Ganz" ändert die Bedeutung von "schön": "Der Wein ist schön trocken" -> "Der Wein ist ganz schön trocken"

Comment: @PiedPiper Da hast du ganz bestimmt recht - meiner Meinung nach ist "ganz schön trocken" eher "pretty dry", wohingegen "schön trocken" "nice and dry" wäre. Das sieht man auch in meiner Antwort, obwohl ich es wahrscheinlich noch klarer machen könnte.

Answer (score -2):

Dein Beispiel kann auf einen einzigen Satz zusammengestutzt werden:

> (Ist er) schön trocken?

*Schön* bedeutet *so, wie wir es mögen*.

Schönheit liegt im Deutschen allein in den Sinnen des Betrachters.

> Da bist du ja schön auf die Nase gefallen.

*Es mag dich überraschen, aber dein Unglück hat auch etwas Positives, das mir gefällt.*

Nichts und niemand ist so unnütz, dass es nicht noch als schlechtes Beispiel dienen könnte.

Comment: "Bis Paris ist es zu Fuß ganz schön weit." Die Frage weist ganz zurecht auf eine zweite Bedeutung hin. Dass Schönheit im Deutschen notwendig im Auge des Betrachters liegen soll hat mit der Frage nichts zu tun, ist m.W. keine spezifisch deutsche Ansicht und gilt in Deutschland auch nicht total. "Schön auf die Nase gefallen" würde ich entweder als Ironie auffassen, oder wie das Parisbeispiel: Gehörig, heftig, ordentlich, ... Dass daran etwas Positives sein soll ist Humbug.

Comment: @Janka Deine vorgeschlagene Bedeutung war sehr allgemein ("so, wie wir es mögen").  Ich kann die Bedeutung des Satzes noch nicht verstehen, nachdem ich deine Antwort gelesen habe.

Answer (score -3):

Ohne weiteren Kontext lässt sich nicht entscheiden, wie der Satz genau gemeint ist. Insbesondere die Frage, wie trocken sie den Wein am liebsten mögen, wie genau sie wissen, wie der andere den Wein mag, beiseite lassend, dass Ironie im Spiel sein könnte.

Es könnte sein, dass der zweite Sprecher trockenen Wein bevorzugt, aber nicht sehr trockenen. Es kann auch sein er will den anderen nur daran erinnern, dass er trockenen Wein bevorzugt oder nur zum Ausdruck bringen, dass er im Moment einen trockenen bevorzugen würde, weil der zu dem passen würde, was er essen will.

Die Überlegung, welche ironische Bedeutung möglich ist, kann man, wie meist bei Ironie, außen vor lassen, weil sie sich auf die gleiche semantische Wortbedeutung stützt, nur dass die Bedeutung nicht ernst gemeint ist. Das ist ja das Funktionsprinzip der Ironie.

Comment: _Jeder Satz_ kann doch theoretisch ironisch gemeint sein. Deswegen kann man ihn trotzdem übersetzen.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Kann man, aber das Muster ist immer das gleiche. Was vordergründig gemeint ist, wird negiert.